# Web-based user-friendly CMS-like frontend for a SQL database?

Tags: web-apps, database, cms

I have a database of some information in a RDBMS, and I would like to let a relatively small group of users to manage it (add and delete records, query it, etc).

Now I'm not too interested in the low-level database operations; they won't need to create (or delete) tables, they don't need to know what a view or an index is; what I'm looking for is something in between a tool like phpMyAdmin or adminer - and a custom-built web app.

Ideally I imagine I would specify some basic models and their properties, like in [django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) - but without the Django part, because I don't use it anywhere - and I would get a semi-automatic web admin interface for managing records.

I am perfectly willing to write a some necessary glue code; but I really don't want to start building up a whole CMS/admin interface from scratch, as it must have been solved a million times already.